# Can LGTM and SGTM be used interchangeablay?

Tags: differences, abbreviations

- LGTM = Looks Good to Me
- SGTM = Sounds Good to Me

I see these two abbreviations used frequently to express "I agree with your idea, go ahead". Can they be used interchangeably? Is there any subtle difference between them?

Comment: Neither one is valid unless your correspondent knows what they mean (the average person won't), and then you should probably stick with the more familiar one.

Comment: @HotLicks yes in my case my correspondents (my colleagues) all knows LGTM/SGTM. I've seen my colleagues use both with roughly the same frequency, so I was wondering if they could be used interchangeably.

Comment: "Sounds" would generally be used in reference to a brief piece of text, while "looks" would be used with a more lengthy piece.

Answer (score 1):

In real life, *looks good to me* is used when the eyes are involved, seeing your brilliant idea. *Sounds good to me* is used when the ears are involved, hearing your brilliant idea.

On the internet, the former would be used if one is viewing a map you drew, while the latter is used if one is reading your suggestion on what movie to watch this weekend.